# Java.lang.long cannot be applied to java.lang.string?

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-handling, hex

I am trying to write a program for converting positive binary inputs into hex.
Why am i getting this errors while compiling my binary to hex converter..

```
BinToHex.java:45: toHexString(long) in java.lang.Long cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
            hexOutput = Long.toHexString(tempDecString);
                            ^
1 error
```

my code..
class BinToHex
    import java.io.*;

```
public class BinToHex {
    double tempDec,fractionpart;
    long longofintpart,templongDec;
    String inpu ="1001.01";
    String hexOutput,intpart,tempDecString,hex = null;

    static int i = 1;

    public void convertbintohex() {

        if (inpu.contains(".")) {
            int placesAfterPoint = inpu.length() - inpu.indexOf(".") - 1;//every thing
            long numerator = Long.parseLong(inpu.replace(".", ""), 2);//goes 
            double decimalOfInput = ((double) numerator) / (1L << placesAfterPoint);//alright  till here 


            while (true) {
                tempDec = decimalOfInput * 16;
                if ((int)tempDec == tempDec) {
                    tempDecString = String.valueOf(tempDec);
                    templongDec = Long.valueOf(tempDecString).longValue();
                    hexOutput = hexOutput+Long.toHexString(templongDec);
                    break;
                } else {
                    intpart = String.valueOf((long)tempDec);
                    longofintpart = Long.valueOf(intpart).longValue();
                    if(i==1){
                        hex=Long.toHexString(longofintpart);
                        hexOutput = hex + ".";
                        i=i+1;
                    }else{
                        hexOutput = hexOutput + hex;
                    }
                    fractionpart = tempDec-(int)tempDec;
                    decimalOfInput = fractionpart;
                }
            }
        } else {
                // this part is ok
            tempDecString = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(inpu, 2));
            templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
            hexOutput = Long.toHexString(tempDecString);
        }
        System.out.println(hexOutput);
    }   
}
```

class Test,,

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    BinToHex i = new BinToHex();
    i.convertbintohex();    
    }
}
```

plz help.
thanks.

Comment: `Long.toHexString` method take `long` as parameter instead of `String`

Comment: By the way, `double` doesn't store a number in decimal. It is only after you convert it to a `String` using `String.valueOf(double)` that it is converted to decimal. And you wouldn't want to do that here, since you want to convert from binary to hex.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, look at the signature of [`Long.toHexString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)):

```
public static String toHexString(long i)
```

You're trying to pass in a string. Given that it's meant to convert a `long` *into* a string, it's not at all clear what you would expect this to do, but that's why you're getting the error - which is exactly what the compiler is telling you. (Compiler errors are sometimes obscure, but in this case they're really not...)

You seem to be doing *far* more conversions than you ought to be. You're doing some hex conversion yourself by the looks of it, and then some conversion to decimal... why are you doing *anything* with a decimal representation if you're converting binary to hex?

It's not really clear what your expected input/output is given that you've got a floating binary point in there, but I would just parse from binary to a `byte[]` and convert that byte array to hex using a 3rd party library... unless you know that the values will only ever be in the range of `long`, in which case it's fine to use `Long.parseLong` and `Long.toHexString`, but those should be *all* you need. Get rid of any conversions to/from decimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
templongDec = Long.parseLong(tempDecString, 10);
hexOutput = Long.toHexString(tempDecString);
```

you are passing the string as paramter to the static method. Change it in

```
hexOutput = Long.toHexString(templongDec);
```